# Unexplainable gap on bottom of web page

Tags: css, web, html, inspector

I'm having an issue with a site we launched recently. There's a 25 pixel gap at the bottom of the site that I cannot explain, and I've exhausted all troubleshooting techniques I could think of trying to figure this out.

http://bit.ly/1I2m3ZD

Here's what I can tell you is NOT causing it:

1) There is no margin or padding on the body or HTML tags. 
2) The footer does not have a bottom margin or padding. 
3) The height of the footer is static. 
4) There are no elements within the footer that are hanging outside of the box. 
5) When I eliminate the both the footer and the content area, the gap is still there.
6) There are no 3rd party apps installed which would affect page layout (and if there were, any dynamic changes would show in Inspector).

I'm using Firefox inspector to troubleshoot this. Inspector is showing nothing that indicates the space should be there, and when I remove elements one at a time by deleting them through the inspector, the gap does not go away. What am I missing?? Either I'd like to learn how to use inspector for troubleshooting better (because I'm obviously not troubleshooting effectively), or I'd just like to find out what could cause this gap and not show up when I try to hunt it down.

Comment: `google_conversion_frame` :)

Comment: [This is off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's also highly susceptible to link rot and will not likely be useful to any future users.

Comment: $%#*&$!!! yeah, that's it. We're so used to adding in google stuff I didn't think to even call this 3rd party app, when it clearly is. So wrapping it in a div and applying { height:0 ; visibility:hidden } does not prevent the gap. { display:none } does, though I'm concerned it may not get picked up. I guess we'll test it and see. The lesser question would be why didn't FX Inspector see it? But I won't lose too much sleep if an answer isn't apparent.

Comment: Paul, for future reference, best step to help resolve this is to open the inspector and add this style: `* { border: 1px solid #f00; }`. The problem appears immediately.

Comment: Well now, that's a great idea. Hah, that's old school troubleshooting - I haven't done site-wide borders in maybe 10 years. Totally makes sense. Thanks for the tip! FYI, { height:0 ; overflow:hidden ; visibility:hidden } **did** hide it without preventing it from working. Good stuff here - thanks guys!

Comment: zzzzBov, for what it's worth, the answers are timeless, even if the link goes bad (highly unlikely this will happen for a very long time, but sure, I can see it). Even with the link removed, the description and answers will be very useful for someone else having the same frustrations troubleshooting their layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should elaborate. The problem is caused by the code `<iframe name="google_conversion_frame"...`

Because this `iframe` is in the flow and has layout, it is being added at the bottom of the page and adding the space. Your best bet would be to apply a style to it, giving it `position: absolute;` and a `left: -5000px;` or similar style to remove it from view.

Comment: trnelson, you get the checkmark for answering it first. Adam J's answer is just as good. FYI, I used { height:0 ; overflow:hidden ; visibility:hidden } to hide it, and this appears to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an iframe at the bottom of your site named 'google_conversion_frame' causing the added spacing. I would suggest adding the following to your CSS:

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
  height: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I have heard that using display: none can cause issues with iframes and tracking pixels but that information may be outdated and so display: none may be fine.